# Spring MVC send email on registration

Tags: java, spring, email, web-applications, gmail

I'm trying to send an email to a user once their account is registered, I can get my code to work in a separate project (simple form input etc) however when I try to add the same code to my app it gives me the following error

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException error

Could not autowire method: public void com.finalProject.school.controller.AppController.setMailSender(org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Here is my code for adding the new user to the database (which works fine) with the code to send an email which is what is giving me errors

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/newuser" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName,
        @RequestParam("password") String password, @RequestParam("email") String emailAddress,
        ModelMap model, Model model2) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }


    if(!userService.isUserSSOUnique(user.getId(), user.getSsoId())){
        FieldError ssoError =new FieldError("user","ssoId",messageSource.getMessage("non.unique.ssoId", new String[]{user.getSsoId()}, Locale.getDefault()));
        result.addError(ssoError);
        return "registration";
    }



    String status = null;

    try {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true,"UTF-8");
        helper.setFrom("Administrator");
        helper.setTo(emailAddress);
        helper.setSubject("Registration confirmation");

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("firstName", firstName);
        params.put("password", password);

        String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "spring/emailRegistration.vm", "UTF-8", params);

        helper.setText(text, true);
        mailSender.send(message);
        status = "Confirmation email is sent to your address (" + emailAddress + ")";
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        status = "There was an error in email sending. Please check your email address: " + emailAddress;
    }

    model2.addAttribute("message", status);

    userService.saveUser(user);

    model.addAttribute("success", "User " + user.getFirstName() + " "+ user.getLastName() + " registered successfully");
    model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
    //return "success";
    return "registrationsuccess";
}
```

Any ideas of how to fix this ?

App Config Class

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.finalProject.school" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot, you probably have not included following properties in your `application.properties` file.

```
spring.mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username = abc@abc.com
spring.mail.password = xyz
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
```

**UPDATE**

Ok. Put the following in your configuration file.

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">

    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="587" />
    <property name="username" value="myemail1@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="password!" />

    <!-- The name of the property, following JavaBean naming conventions -->
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have those in my application.properties and also added the mail dependency in my pom.xml file

Comment: I cant see a reason why spring boot's auto configuration would not load bean if you have already included the dependency in pom.xml and added the properties in your application.properties, unless you have defined some conditional configuration. Can you provide your application's configuration?

Comment: @lulubelle - I cant see a reason why spring boot's auto configuration would not load bean if you have already included the dependency in pom.xml and added the properties in your application.properties, unless you have defined some conditional configuration. Can you provide your application's configuration?

Comment: I have added my app config class that, is that the class you wanted ?